# How to search across a directory of files in vim?

Tags: vim, editing

A common programming task for me in vim is:

```
:s/some pattern/
```

do some work

`n #` finds the next entry

do some work

`n #` finds the next entry
...

Now, `s/....` only searches in the current file.

Is there a way I can do this, but search across a *directory* of files? Say do "s/..../" over all files in subdirectoires of `pwd` that ends in ***.hpp*** of **.cpp** ?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just a kind of workaround, so I'm not posting it as an answer: you can open all the files in one vim session so you can :n to the next one, then record a macro that does :s/.../ and :n and execute the macro a sufficiently large number of times. (running the macro too often won't do any harm, as the substitution will simply be tried again and again for the last file)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can simply use the [`:grep` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#grep): or for a more complete integration of search tools, use the [grep.vim extension](https://github.com/vim-scripts/grep.vim).

Simply type `:help grep` to get a nice documentation of what is available out of the box in Vim.
Using `:grep foo *.?pp` should do what you want.
This will open the [QuickFix list](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix), just like the one you get using `:make`, enabling to jump to the found occurrences.

Comment: Nice answer! after install grep.vim, we can use :Grep something  \*/\*.cpp

Comment: Or you can use `:vimgrep`.

Answer (score 7):

There is a fantastic plugin named [ctrlsf.vim](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim) ,which makes you search in vim efficiently.

Here is a snapshot of it.Quite cool ,isn't it?

[image]

For instance , If you want search word like "hello" in current dir , after installation , all you need to do is Simply type：

```
:CtrlSF "hello"
```

then you'll get what you expect.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

```
:help windo
:help bufdo
man find
man xargs

find ./start/point -iname "*.cpp" -print0 | xargs -0 vim
:bufdo s/baar/foo/gc
:wall
:qall
```

gc "global confirm", wall (write all), qall (quite all). To see file list :ls top jump to next file :wn (write next) or :bn (buffer next). By the way, xargs manage large chunks of file in memory to deliver to vim withou erros.